# ASP.NET Web.config debugging

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I've uploaded a working application to my hosting web server and one page that I was working throws an error. In my web.config I have setting like this:

```
....
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="errorpage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="bannedaddress.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.htm" />
</customErrors>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
....
```

and I am redirected to errorpage.htm even though customErrors mode is set to Off. I can't find any info about the error (other than it occured) in the log files.

The question is: what should I change to be able to debug the app?

Answer (score 0):

Could be your IIS settings, depending on the host you may be able to access the IIS error files. It could be that your IIS is redirecting to that page and not your application.

Your `customErrors` should not be redirecting when the mode is off.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a virtual application? In that case, you might want to set `<customErrors mode="Off" />` on the parent directory aswell.